Error writing configuration file on fresh install of CiviCRM on Backdrop
When doing a fresh install of CiviCRM 5.78.3 on Backdrop 1.29.1 (also a fresh install) using cv, I get this error:
In config.inc line 1723:

  [ConfigStorageException]
  Failed to write configuration file: ./files/config_144d1c53daf8087de3bda29d
  6e678c0d/active/user.role.authenticated.json

The file in question exists (it was put there during the Backdrop install) and appears to be untouched.  Directory permission are correct.  The config.inc file is part of Backdrop core, so I don't know whether this is a problem with Backdrop or CiviCRM.
Trace:
Exception trace:
  at <basedir>/core/includes/config.inc:1723
 ConfigFileStorage->write() at <basedir>/core/includes/config.inc:1013
 Config->save() at <basedir>/core/modules/user/user.module:2622
 user_role_save() at <basedir>/core/modules/user/user.module:2756
 user_role_grant_permissions() at <basedir>/modules/civicrm/setup/plugins/installDatabase/FlushBackdrop.civi-setup.php:58
 civicrm_install_set_backdrop_perms() at <basedir>/modules/civicrm/setup/plugins/installDatabase/FlushBackdrop.civi-setup.php:29
 Civi\Setup::{closure}() at <basedir>/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:230
 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners() at <basedir>/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:59
 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() at <basedir>/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:263
 Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch() at <basedir>/modules/civicrm/setup/src/Setup.php:230
 Civi\Setup->installDatabase() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Command/CoreInstallCommand.php:131
 Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->runSetup() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Command/CoreInstallCommand.php:66
 Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:155
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:680
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:218
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/lib/src/BaseApplication.php:98
 Civi\Cv\BaseApplication->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:124
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/lib/src/BaseApplication.php:65
 Civi\Cv\BaseApplication->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/lib/src/BaseApplication.php:27
 Civi\Cv\BaseApplication::main() at phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/bin/cv:29
 require() at /usr/local/bin/cv:15

Any suggestions about how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Are you running cv as the same OS user that runs the webserver?  Do you get an error from touch ./files/config_144d1c53daf8087de3bda29d6e678c0d/active/user.role.authenticated.json  What do you get from ls -ld files files/config_144d1c53daf8087de3bda29d6e678c0d files/config_144d1c53daf8087de3bda29d6e678c0d/active ?

Running cv as a regular user.  I ran 'chown -R myuser:_www files' and then 'chmod -R chmod -R g+rw files' then reran the install.  That seems to have fixed the problem.  Thank you!
